# SharePoint Development?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, development

I am looking to get started learning more at SharePoint Development. I have pushed SharePoint Workflow as far as I think I can push it. I am looking for some guidance on where to start learning more delvish style, even if it means learning a program language and/or creating apps.

I am working with both on prem and Cloud.

**Edit:**
I guess what I am really asking is it worth while endeavor to learn a Language like C# or something else to do developing for Office 365 mostly SharePoint. If so what have steps would you suggest.

Comment: Do you want to do development for workflows only? or development in general?

Comment: Mostly workflows, but willing to learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to get into SharePoint development, then focus on JavaScript, and CSOM. Start thinking about doing what you used to do in previous versions using JavaScript & CSOM. A console applications for example to do provisioning. Back this up with learning the new open source tools which would be required to get started with [SharePoint Framework](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview), familiarize yourself with NodeJS (but don't dive deep in it, just know its purpose and what it is) & npm, Gulp, Yeoman, and TypeScript.

One source of information would be to follow [PnP team](https://dev.office.com/patterns-and-practices) and stay up to date with what's going on there. They have already built cool stuff that you can reuse, such as the [provisioning engine](https://dev.office.com/patterns-and-practices-detail/5821), so instead of depending on features to provision stuff, now you can do so from a console application.

For the workflows, I suggest to learn how to package workflows in an add-in and deploy it to SharePoint, and not to focus too much on SharePoint designer.